# Select unique rows based on column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, unique

The original table has three not unique columns, where id value separate data by groups:

```
id  name                flag
----------------------------
1   Andrey              0
1   Andrey              1
1   Olga                0
1   Sasha               0
2   Masha               1
2   Masha               0
2   Katya               1
2   Vera                0
```

Here we have two groups of people, where each group has two rows with equal names. I would like to write a select statemets which duplicate name rows with flag 0, if and only if this exact name has 1 flag in the same group.

So, expected result for this data should be:

```
id  name                flag
----------------------------
1   Andrey              1
2   Masha               1
```

because Andrey and Masha are duplicates and they have 0 flag too.

My attempt to select these values is to use query like following:

```
select * from names
    where flag = 1 and id in
    (select id from names where flag = 0)
```

but it's returns Katya row too, what is unexcepted.

Comment: please tag your database as well

Comment: What if Masha has one id = 2, and one id = 5? Still return Masha?

Comment: @jarlh - in case where we have two instances of Masha with id 2 and id 5 we don't need to return it, because these instances located in different groups (id is an index of group).

Comment: @vkp - this question is mostly theoretical. Anyway, I specified database engine I am using right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT n.* FROM  Names n
WHERE n.flag = 1
AND EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM Names n2
  WHERE n.id = n2.id 
    AND n.name = n2.name
    AND n2.flag = 0
)
```

Comment: Thank you, Tim! It's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `intersect` operator to get the `name` which has both the flags.

```
select name from names where flag = 0
intersect 
select name from names where flag = 1
```

In MySQL, you could do,

```
select n1.name 
from names n1 
join names n2 on n1.name = n2.name and n2.flag = 1
where n1.flag = 0
```

Comment: Thank vkp! Wonderful exampe to use inersect statement.